# Override Paperclip:Attachment method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I need to access the url from an attachment when it is upload, as such I have to define the `after_flush_writes` method like it is suggested here https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/816

How can I achieve that?

So far I have done this, but it does not work:

```
class ExcelFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :insertion 
  has_attached_file :excel
  validates_attachment_content_type :excel, content_type: [ "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                    "application/msword",
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"]


  def after_flush_writes
    super
    byebug
    file = Roo::Excelx.new(self.excel.url(:original, timestamp: false))
    input_from_generals self.id, file
    input_from_financials self.id, file
  end
```

I tried to use the `after_commit`, `after_create` callbacks to be able to access the `self.excel.url` but it does not work.

Comment: The `after_flush_writes` would have to be defined in the context of `Paperclip::Attachment class`, otherwise it will not be called. However, my tests show that a simple `after_create` or `after_save` callbacks work OK - you should be able to use the `url` inside these callbacks.

Comment: Thanks! @BoraMa I'm not able to do it with after_create or after_save and I think it is because the paperclip writes out the file via after_save callback.

Comment: My question is similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960471/paperclip-running-a-method-after-the-file-is-saved but I don't know how they solved the problem.

Comment: The question you linked is different - the OP needed to do something with the **physical file**, thus he needed it to be flushed to the disk at the moment of the callback. You only need the URL which, in my tests, works OK even before physically saving the file to disk. What exactly is the problem in your case?

Comment: No, I also need the physical file. The URL is generated properly and I'm able to get it right, but I get an error saying  "File not found" because I need the physical file to read some data.

Comment: I see. Does my answer below help? (Although while posting it I admit that if it does work, I do not understand why using the `after_commit` callback did not work for you.)

Comment: One last note: I think you need to use `path` method instead of `url`. `path` returns the path to the physical file whereas `url` returns the public path used in links (URLs). With `path` you would not need to remove "public" from the path. It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be related to the order of callbacks.

As discussed in the comments above, the attachment file is indeed physically saved to disk in an `after_save` [callback defined in Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb#L92) which is added to the model class at the point of  `has_attached_file` call.

So you must ensure that your own `after_save` callbacks (that want to deal with the uploaded file) **are defined after** the `has_attached_line`.

Note: the `after_create` callback indeed cannot be used at all as it is called before `after_save`.

Comment: It works with after_save and the 'public' prefix in the URL.